# Unanimous Approval but not all approvers are required on every record

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have an approval process for an Opportunity record that requires unanimous approval for a Department review step from up to 6 approvers.  The approvers are configured as 6 custom lookup fields called Related User fields.  The issue is I have is that some Opportunities do not require all 6 approvers.  Hence the lookup is left blank for those that are not required.  It appears the Approval process requires all 6 approvers even though some of the related user lookup fields are left blank as certain approvals just are not needed for that Opportunity.

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: 1. Do they have to be notified all at once? 2. Are they really on kind of same level or is there some delegation of authority at play? I'm thinking along the lines of "Joe is authorized to approve purchase orders up to $ 5K, anything above that has to hit Jim and if it's over $100K we need to ask CEO".

Answer (score 1):

Create two separate approval processes.  Modify the entry criteria for each to direct them to the proper approval based on your opportunity object (whichever field lets you know you need unanimous or not).  One approval will be for unanimous and the other will not.

Comment: Based on the last bit of your question that I re-read I think the same approach could be used but check for the approval field to be null.  You'd have to replicate that up to 6 times if you can have anywhere from 1-6 approvers.  Perhaps someone has a better idea.  That seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Another option could be to use apex to set the approvers.  The advantage is less maintenance than having 6 approval processes, but the downside is maintaining the code to make changes. See documentation here:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Approval_ProcessRequest_instance_methods.htm